# What is the best way to display a feed of different media types?

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently created a php file named feed.php which is designed to fetch items from a MySQL database and display them (in a news feed style way) on a webpage. The way that I've done it involves using 19 if/elseif/else statements - and this number is growing.

In short, what these statements do is decide how the information is displayed. I'll include the code below, but it is quite long and repetitive.

```
<?

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM mainfeed ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0 , 1000";

$comments = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo "<h1>Recent Posts</h1><br><br><hr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comments, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $comment = $row['comment'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
  $file = $row['file'];
  $info = pathinfo($file);
  $info['extension'];
  $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $ytlink = $row['ytlink'];
  $tag = $row['tag'];
  $tag2 = $row['tag2'];
  $tag3 = $row['tag3'];
  $handle = $row['handle'];
  $score = $row['score'];
  $id = $row['id'];

  $ytarray=explode("/", $ytlink);
  $ytendstring=end($ytarray);
  $ytendarray=explode("?v=", $ytendstring);
  $ytendstring=end($ytendarray);
  $ytendarray=explode("&", $ytendstring);
  $ytcode=$ytendarray[0];

  $display = Array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'PNG', 'gif');
  $vid = Array('MOV', 'mov', 'mp4');


if($tag != ''){
    $tagdisp = "<br><a href='/$tag' class='posttag'>$tag</a>";

}

elseif($tag==''){
    $tagdisp="";

}

if($tag2 != ''){
    $tagdisp2 = "<a href='/$tag2' class='posttag'>$tag2</a>";

}

elseif($tag2==''){
    $tagdisp2="";

}

if($tag3 != ''){
    $tagdisp3 = "<a href='/$tag3' class='posttag'>$tag3</a>";

}

elseif($tag3==''){
    $tagdisp3="";

}

if($tag != 'explicit' && $tag2 != 'explicit' && $tag3 != 'explicit'){

if ($file != NULL) {

  if (in_array($info['extension'], $display)){

  echo " <div class='card'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
      <a href='$file'><img src='$file' style='width:70%; margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%; margin-top:5px; border-style:none;'></a><br>
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";
  }

  elseif(in_array($info['extension'], $vid)) {
    echo " <div class='card'>
    <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
    <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
     <video controls='controls' width='70%' src='$file' style='border-style: solid'></video><br>
    <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
    <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
   ";
}

  else {

  echo " <div class='card'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
      <a href='$file'><h3>Click Here To View Attached File</h3></a><br>
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";

  }
}

elseif($ytlink != NULL) {

  echo " <div class='card'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
      <iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$ytcode\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";

}

else {

  echo " <div class='card'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br />
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";

}

}

if($tag == 'explicit' OR $tag2 == 'explicit' OR $tag3 == 'explicit'){

if ($file != NULL) {

  if (in_array($info['extension'], $display)){

  echo " <div class='cardexp'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
      <img src='$file' style='width:70%; margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%; margin-top:5px; border-style:solid;'><br>
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";
  }

  elseif(in_array($info['extension'], $vid)) {
    echo " <div class='cardexp'>
    <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
    <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
     <video controls='controls' width='70%' src='$file' style='border-style: solid'></video><br>
    <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
    <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
   ";
}

  else {

  echo " <div class='cardexp'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
      <a href='$file'><h3>Click Here To View Attached File</h3></a><br>
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";

  }
}

elseif($ytlink != NULL) {

  echo " <div class='cardexp'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />
      <iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$ytcode\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";

}


else {

  echo " <div class='cardexp'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br />
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";

}

}

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I feel like the method I've used to create this feed (and the way I've told the browser to display the different media types, is probably not the best way in which I could have done it.

If I were to rewrite this file, what would be the best (most efficient and effective) way of achieving the same result?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCardTemplate($comment, $id, $score, $tagdisp, $tagdisp2, $tagdisp3, $timestamp, $innerTemplate) {
  return " <div class='card'>
      <h3>Handle: $handle</h3><br />
      <p>$comment</p><br /><br />".$innerTemplate. 
     "<p>Post #$id</p>
      <p id='scorecount-$id'>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>&#8679;</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>&#8681;</button><br>
      <br>$tagdisp $tagdisp2 $tagdisp3<br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";
}
```

And you pass the text needed as `$innerTemplate`. You will still have many cases, but it will be less repetitive and much more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Would this improve the browser load time of the webpage?

Comment: @JohnSmith, no, your question was about modifying your coding style and my answer focuses on that. If my answer helped you write a code easier to work with, then you might consider accepting it. As about the speed issue, you should ask a question about that separately, showing us the structure and row number of mainfeed. You would need to look into indexes and load only the columns you will actually use in your code.